# how to make ffserver working well in real time

Tags: ffserver

I used to ffserver streaming my webcam it works well but the problem when I ' uses VLC or ffplay to retrieve the stream is noted that the streaming is not in real time and also is not continuous .

- ffserver.conf
- Port 8090
- BindAddress 0.0.0.0
- MaxClients 4
- MaxBandwidth 10000
- NoDaemo
- TSPPort 7654
- RTSPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
- File /tmp/webcam.ffm
- FileMaxSize 5M
- feed webcam.ffm
- Format flv
- VideoCodec flv
- VideoFrameRate 2
- VideoBufferSize 20000
- VideoBitRate 200
- VideoQMin 5
- VideoQMax 10
- VideoSize qvga
- PreRoll 0
- Noaudio

and i used command line

```
 ffmpeg -s 160x128 -f video4linux -i /dev/video0 -r 15
  http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm
```

Answer (score 1):

May be increase the bitrate and the resolution.

I have used the following parameters in my config file for webm over HTML5 without video

```
<Stream test1.webm>            # Output stream URL definition
   Feed feed1.ffm              # Feed from which to receive video
   Format webm

   # Audio settings
   #AudioCodec vorbis
   #AudioBitRate 64             # Audio bitrate
   NoAudio
   # Video settings
   VideoCodec libvpx
   VideoBufferSize 4
   #VideoCodec libx264
   VideoSize  720x576          # Video resolution
   VideoGopSize 2  
   #VideoIntraOnly 
   VideoFrameRate 25           # Video FPS
   AVOptionVideo flags +global_header
   AVOptionVideo quality realtime
   AVOptionVideo min-q 2 
   AVOptionVideo max-q 56
   AVOptionVideo target-bitrate 1000
   AVOptionVideo undershoot-pct 90
   AVOptionVideo buf-sz 60
   AVOptionVideo buf-initial-sz 4
   AVOptionVideo buf-optimal-sz 50
   AVOptionVideo kf-max-dist 999999
   AVOptionVideo deadline realtime
   AVOptionVideo passes 1

   PreRoll 0
   StartSendOnKey
   VideoBitRate 1000            # Video bitrate
</Stream>
```